# How could I change button titles in Swift back to the defaults with a button (It's been changed to something else in the app)

Tags: swift

How could I change button titles in Swift back to the defaults with a button (after it's been changed to something else in the app)

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? How is the title being changed? Is it possible to just store the initial value in a variable and set the title to that initial value whenever you need to?

Comment: It's a Tic-Tac-Toe game, and if the user click on one of the buttons (1-9), it changes to a symbol that indicates that he chose that. But I couldn't figure out how to change all of them back after somebody wins

Comment: And I used an array to store which one was chosen in order to evaluate

Comment: Could you post some code to show how you're creating that list of buttons? I imagine you could loop over that array to access each button individually

Comment: If the user touch one of the buttons then I change the button text to the user's symbol and I get the original (1-9) this into the array and after that I check whether sy won or not. So after the game ends it's possible that every buttons title changes to one of the two symbols, so it's impossible to put back the 1-9 numbers. So I think the only option would be to restart the app without restarting

Comment: You could use a for loop (for var i = 0; i < buttons.count; i++) to loop over the button array and then set the button title to i+1. This should set each button title to a number from 1 to 9. I added an answer with an example.

Answer (score 0):

Example code to do what I describe in my comment:

```
// creating the buttons
var buttons: [UIButton] = [UIButton]()
for i in 0..<9 {
    let btn: UIButton = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.System) as! UIButton
    btn.setTitle("\(i+1)", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    buttons.append(btn)
}

// resetting the buttons
for var i = 0; i < buttons.count; i++ {
    buttons[i].setTitle("\(i+1)", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
}
```

Comment: Here is the project: https://www.dropbox.com/s/jpgmt7z8xqzyixb/Tic-Tac-Toe.v1.png?dl=0